# Wampserver icon not going green fully, mysql services not starting up?

Tags: mysql, apache, wampserver

I'm running an application on `localhost`, it's been running successfully for at least a year now, but suddenly today wampserver isn't starting up. Whenever I rightclick on the taskbar icon and "start all services", it gets orange, but never green. Yesterday there was a data loss problem because one of the mysql tables crashed and had to be repaired, if that's related to this in any way.

If I try `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, I get a `403 Forbidden` error, which I never got before.

I checked the apache log today and its latest entries are:

```
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:0, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. mysql_real_escape_string() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:25, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php on line 25, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:0, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:31 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. mysql_real_escape_string() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:25, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php on line 26, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:0, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. mysql_real_escape_string() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:26, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n in D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php on line 26, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:0, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. mysql_real_escape_string() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:26, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php on line 26, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:0, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:32 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. mysql_real_escape_string() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:26, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php on line 34, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:0, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. mysql_num_rows() D:\\wamp\\www\\zeejflow\\index_exe.php:34, referer: http://localhost/zeejflow/index.php
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
[Sat Jul 20 14:17:33 2013] [error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
```

Lines 25 and 26 on index_exe.php are simply as below (I was trying to log in to the application):

```
$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
```

Because of the `[2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively  (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306` error, I figured maybe there's a problem with some other application using the same port, so I tried the following (my wamp is running on D:) :

```
C:\Users\admin>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         localhost127:49313     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         localhost127:49317     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49155        localhost127:49156     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49156        localhost127:49155     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49157        localhost127:49158     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49158        localhost127:49157     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49311        localhost127:49312     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49312        localhost127:49311     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49313        localhost127:5939      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49315        localhost127:49316     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49316        localhost127:49315     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49317        localhost127:5939      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49320        localhost127:49321     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49321        localhost127:49320     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.15.200:49166   server6201:5938        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.15.200:49847   Server-PC:netbios-ssn  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.15.200:49848   Server-PC:netbios-ssn  TIME_WAIT

D:\>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49799     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49800     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49801     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49802     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49803     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49804     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49806     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49810     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           localhost127:49811     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         localhost127:49313     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         localhost127:49317     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49155        localhost127:49156     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49156        localhost127:49155     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49157        localhost127:49158     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49158        localhost127:49157     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49311        localhost127:49312     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49312        localhost127:49311     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49313        localhost127:5939      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49315        localhost127:49316     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49316        localhost127:49315     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49317        localhost127:5939      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49320        localhost127:49321     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49321        localhost127:49320     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.15.200:49166   server6201:5938        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.15.200:49805   mrs02s05-in-f4:http    ESTABLISHED
```

But now I don't know what to make of this. I made sure my.ini had specified port 3306, and it had (anyway noone changed it in a year how could it suddenly have another value). Any help please! I think Apache is working because when I type in `http://localhost`, it works and gives the option to go to phpmyadmin or my application folder, but it appears mysql services aren't starting up or something? I confirmed with the admin and no new software (such as Skype) have been installed or anything.

### Update

I went to `Services.msc` and checked `wampapache`,  the status was "started".
But `wampmysqld` had no status. So I right-clicked and chose "Start".
A message said "Windows is attempting to start the service on the local computer", but then I got this  error:

```
Windows could not start the wampmysqld service on Local Computer
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly
```

What on earth is up? :(

### Update 2

I got the mysql working again, here:

[mysqld working but wampmysqld not starting up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770846/mysqld-working-but-wampmysqld-not-starting-up/17770958#17770958)

HowEVER, `localhost://phpmyadmin` still gives me a `403 forbidden` error, and `mysql_connect` keeps giving me an "Access denied" error.

Comment: You need to look at your `Windows Event Viewer` and in the Application section look for messages from MYSQL. There may well be a better more specific erro message in there.

Answer (score 15):

Go to: `wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data` and delete the following:

`auto.cnf`, `xxxxxxxxx.err`, `xxxxxxxxx.pid`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`

leave other file as it is.

if it is skype that is occupying your port 80 then go to skype: tools>option and in advance>connection uncheck "use port 80 and 443......"

Comment: thanks. That works for me, and it is the only solution, which is works for me. You guy is really great....

Comment: there is not `data` folder for me

Comment: Worked for me too. Also if anyone is unable to delete the log files Goto TaskManager > mysqld > EndTask > Exit wamp and delete

Answer (score 13):

This happened to me today. Since I had not changed my system setting since yesterday, I assumed it's predominantly a mysql issue on the system. I managed to fix it in the following way.

1. Open wampserver's mysql log file. This will contain information on why the service threw and error and exited prematurely.
2. In my case, the mysql service failed to start because it could not read a certain tablespace. The specific tablespace was indicated in the log.
3. Failure to read such a file could be because of file permissions or the file being broken. In such a case, mysql stops executing in order to avoid damaging a tablespace file that may be linked to a database you need. Usually, if you have a backup of the database, then it is safe to simply delete this problematic file and restore the database once your mysql service is started again.
4. If you do not have a database backup then you could force the mysql instance to run a recovery by enabling the option in your my.cnf / my.ini file.

innodb_force_recovery = 1

This forces the instance to run the crash recovery.

**NOTE:** installing a new instance of mysql does not necessarily mean that your databases shall be retained. I suggest you run a nightly backup of your databases if you are working on huge projects.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, to resolve it I added the following line to my.ini

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Comment: Worked for me too... Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me .. Thank you dear !

Answer (score 5):

I was running Wamp Server for more than a year,
Now I faced a problem that I couldn't start Wamp server (The icon just stay red and the error message appear)

I managed to uninstall Wamp and reinstall it again, and so I did, but before that I copied the folder from mysql/data to my desktop then when I reinstall it I copied that files to the original location.

Then mysql just got confused... And phpmyadmin is not working so I fixed that by restoring the fresh install folder contents..
But I couldn't start mysql (the wamp servers icon still on yellow)

So after I googled a lot, I deleted every thing in the mysql/data except for:-

```
mysql
test
performance_schema
```

And my problem solved :)

Comment: I am using wampServer3.0.9, no need reinstall and just follow your instruction, delete all the files except database folder. Than restart all the service, and working fine now.

Comment: Wow, re-reading that after almost 4 years. I barely understood that. I may have to go edit it for future reference. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem...

WampServer has been running fine since Feb on my local dev server. Today I couldn't get it to run.

Off to google where I found this page and found no answers until I saw the last entry:

"1.Run WampServer: Apache->service->test port 80.

2.Find out application which occupation port 80(e.g. skype)"

So did and it returned that Skype was possibly blocking port 80.

Turned off Skype and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

-Go to Task Manger
-End all task instances of mysql
-restart your wampserver

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Mysql didn't start.

1. go to services.
2. right click the wampmysqld go to properties.
3. startup type select manual.
4. right click and click start service.

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding *innodb_force_recovery=3* to *my.ini* solved the issue

Another option is removing *ibdata* files and all *ib_logfile* from the *data* directory , as explained in [MySQL docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-creating-innodb.html). However this will cause any innoDB tables not to work(because the some information stored in *ibdata1*)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reset data from MySQL

- delete previous data from C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data
- restart service

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything from this file.

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\data\mysql-bin.index
```

Restart mysql server and it should work.

Comment: no, the answer for this case is doing what @user2845576 suggested and is adding **innodb_force_recovery = 1** in [wampmysqld] section.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run WampServer: Apache->service->test port 80.
2. Find out what application which occupies the port 80(e.g. skype)
3. Shut down and restarts WampServer.

Answer (score 0):

I opened up services.msc from the command prompt and disabled **SQL Server reporting services**

& **SQL Server analysis services**. These services were using port 80.

Then I restarted WAMP Server and it started working properly as before.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled the WampServer completelly, and deleted all files in /wamp folder, except www. This folder is preserved when uninstalling. After that I've installed it again and it works fine.

Important: This is helpful only in case when you already have your database backed up. All data from the database will be wiped out this way.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything from this file.

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\data\mysql-bin.index

It works for me. My wamp server has turned green. Tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on wamp (Yellow) icon
2. Go Apache-> Service-> Test port 80. If port is available to use
   then go to Apache->Service-> Install Service
3. then click on Restart All Services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just changing the port number of MySQL and see if it works?

1. Right click your WAMP icon
2. Choose MySQL, in the menu choose "Use a port other than 3306"
3. Change port number to be "3307"

Answer (score 0):

I've got a very similar problem, after a lot trying even the solutions in this question I concluded with [THIS OTHER ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689969/1920145).

I didn't replicated it here because it is [NOT A CORRECT THING TO DO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104231/305276).

Basically is about re-installing MySQL (or the entire package) being sure to delete very well the old my-sql-data very well (back it up if you might need it) and stick on using 32 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

simplest this to do is find what other service is using the same service id as mysql does in windows.

When i looked through the list of services running on my pc (even after a restart...i still had the problem)

I quickly realised i had webmatrix installed on my computer previous to wamp server...webmatrix installed its own copy of mysql and set it to automatically startup another instance each time i logged in.

As soon as the other instance of mysql associated with web matrix was stopped (and changed from automatic startup to manual) my problem with WAMP mysql was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was running on the same problem, wampmysqld64 did not start, so I checked the Mysql log which you should find it inside the main wamp64 folder, and I found all the details on why is not working. on my computer I found another mysql instance is running so it prevents the wampmysqld64  to start. I stopped the other instance, and everything works fine after.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem just by following below steps:

- On windows platform press WINDOWS + R
- Put services.msc and press OK
- Stop already running MySQL and
- Go to Wamp and start/resume MySQL service

All the best

Answer (score 0):

Click on wampserver icon then -> Apache -> httpd.conf -> search listen here you will find port number like this `#Listen 12.34.56.78:80`
Listen 80 change this port number with any other number like `Listen 12.34.56.78:81` save this and now restart all servers it gets green to orange.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same probelm for the past 3 days. Try this. It will definitely work. 
BEFORE proceeding with the installation of Wampserver, you must ensure that certain elements are installed on your system, otherwise Wampserver will absolutely not run, and in addition, the installation will be faulty and you will need to remove Wampserver BEFORE installing the elements that were missing.
Uninstall wamp and download and Install microsoft visual c++ redistributable 2008 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29), microsoft visual c++ redistributable 2012 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679), microsoft visual c++ redistributable 2015 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145). Now, reinstall wamp and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. This works for me. Unistall the wamp server
Make sure this dependencies are successfully installed **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages** **vcredist_Allversions(x32 orx64)** depending on your OS.
Reinstall the wamp server and you are good to go. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically this happens when you have  not installed pre required software installed on your machine while installing Wampserver you might have got error bellow error at the time of installation.

```
program can't start because msvcr120.dll is missing OR

program can't start because msvcr120.dll is missing
```

If you fixed those issue after the installation of wampserver then you might get stuck at this problem.

**Then You can simply uninstall and install wamp server again**

And If you have not install pre required dependency then first of all uninstall wampserver . And then install pre requirement first and then finally you can install Wampserver and it should work now.

you can download Pre-required applications from following link

**For x64 Machines**

microsoft visual c++ 2010 redistributable package (x64) https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

**For x86 Machines**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

> **Note:- Take backup of your project files before uninstall**

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that wampmysqld64 service was disabled, so I went to:
task manager > services > right click on wampmysqld64 and then properties, another window is gonna open, look for wampmysqld64 service then right click and then click on properties and a window is gonna pop up:

[image: wampmysqld64 properties window]

On "Startup type" just change it from disabled to automatic, then go back click on the service and run it and that's it wamp logo it's gonna turn green.