# How to find which programs are also accessing innodb files and blocking mysql process?

Tags: mysql, innodb, wampserver

Follow up from : [Wampserver icon not going green fully, mysql services not starting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761931/wampserver-icon-not-going-green-fully-mysql-services-not-starting-up)

I have wampserver but the `wampmysqld` process isn't starting up all of a sudden.
I tried `mysqld.exe --console` on the command line and got the following messages:

```
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin>mysqld.exe --console
130721 11:33:00 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130721 11:33:00  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130721 11:33:00  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130721 11:33:00  InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.
InnoDB: This might be a backup or antivirus software or another instance
InnoDB: of MySQL. Please close it to get rid of this error.
```

Now how can I find out which program is also using InnoDB's files?
I've shut down and restarted the services many times, and also shut down and restarted the computer. I have also deleted all the flat files in mysql's `/data` folder, so that it now includes only other folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is download and install Process Explorer from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) then run it and use it's search for strings facility to see which running processes have handles to you file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

> Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open?
>   Now you can find out. Process Explorer shows you information about
>   which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded.