# mysqld working but wampmysqld not starting up

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Following up from here: [Wampserver icon not going green fully, mysql services not starting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761931/wampserver-icon-not-going-green-fully-mysql-services-not-starting-up)

I can see that `mysqld` is working now. But `wampmysqld` is still not working as a service!

```
d:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin>mysqld.exe --console
130721 12:10:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130721 12:10:45  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130721 12:10:45  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130721 12:10:45  InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130721 12:10:45  InnoDB: 1.1.4 started; log sequence number 1595675
130721 12:10:45 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130721 12:10:45 [Note] mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.8'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I've deleted all files in the mysql `/data/` folder and when I ran `mysqld`, a new ibdata1 file was created. So handling InnoDB files seems fine. But wampmysqld still gives `Error 1067`.

These are the last lines on the mysql error log generated by wampserver:

```
130720 10:28:45 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
130720 10:28:46  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130720 10:28:52  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 29711976
130720 10:28:52 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

This means it closed down yesterday morning around half past ten, and it's just not starting up after that!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, and solution was:

go to services,(type command services.msc in run) find mysql service which is installed outside of wamp right click on it and stop.
then again in services panel go to wampmysqld64-> right click-> start

if you need only wamp's mysql version then you can turn other mysql service off.

it fixed my problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: interesting, how come this started happening? was using wamp just fine, dev database, one day this. your comment worked for me, but why and why now? can i do something to remedy this now rather than doing this service swap every time? thank you much btw!

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me: http://jinengbali.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/mysql-server-stop-working-in-wampserver-error-wampmysqld-shutdown-complete/

I installed an "addon" and then from the wampserver icon selected > MySQL > Version and selected one of the newly installed version. The icon finally went green!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it shouldn't work. 
Apparently you have hard-copied some database files into "data" folder.
Just let you know, the mysql doesn't like such things and will never ever start. Just imagine for security reasons that somebody added files to your server. Probably you have added those files while the server was already started and no issues were expected.

Two things you could do:

1. Remove the index file mysql-bin.index on Linux( i do not know the corresponding file for Windows).
2. You should simply remove the added files from 'data' folder and it will then turn to green.

Rule: Try to add databases by csv import options, but never add them manually as folders.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall the entire wampserver again in your computer the wampmysqld file will be allocated back by system .as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem go to mysql and open up the log file should find the cause of the error .

1.In my case the log file was absent so I created a new one.

2.In another case you could have a read error on your log file so could result to an error in this case just locate and delete the problematic file my path for the file "C:\wamp\logs" once it is done try openning the sql log from wamp panel.

3.If you tried all of the above methods and had no result try to look in the log file the cause of your possible error and google it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. How I resolved it was that the port no. assigned to wampmysql was 3306 which was used by another service, so right clicking on wamp icon->tools->use a port other than 3306(under port used by mysql)->change port no. say 3310->press enter. And icon turned green and started working.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Even better than changing port no. as it gives database error is to stop service on the same port in services.msc (windows+r)in my case was mySql57