# Windows: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

Yes, I know there are already a billion threads opened for this issue but so far, none of the solutions has worked for me. I'm having so much trouble trying to get phpmyadmin to work. My error:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried:

- changing the password on `config.inc.php` in wamp to 'root'
- switching to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` instead of `'config'`
- mysql command line to change the password `mysqladmin -u root password root`
- it is running on `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin` but the config has it as `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`, but switching to `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` only gives me a "Not found" error, switching config to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:8080';` also throws an error

The MySQL portion on wamp isn't lighting up, and when I tried starting the service I'm getting the error:

```
    Windows could not start the Mysql service on Local Computer.
    Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

My MySQL is version 5.6.17. Please help! I have a project due soon and this is giving me so much grief.

Comment: You may did something wrong while installing MySQL? Your windows is 64bit? and what is the full path to MySQL?

Comment: @ClearBoth the path in wamp is `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17`

Comment: Try to kill the service and starting it again. Also make sure the path of data file is the same as what written in my.ini file

Comment: Are any other programs currently using port 80? If so, kill them and attempt to start MySQL again.

Comment: @ClearBoth have tried it multiple times, not working :(

Comment: @JulesWinnfield it's on port 8080 and the login was fine, it's just denying me access.

Comment: maybe the password is incorrect then.. reset it

Comment: Have you tampered with, removed, or pasted any files/folders into `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data`? This could cause WAMP to be unable to launch the mysql service, which could be why the service fails shortly after attempting to start it.

Comment: @JulesWinnfield nope

Comment: Hmmm... Try checking out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761931/wampserver-icon-not-going-green-fully-mysql-services-not-starting-up)

Comment: @JulesWinnfield MYSQL runs on port 3306 by default. Its Apache that would normally run on port 80 but he has change that to 8080

Comment: Look at the `\wamp\logs\mysql.log` if that is empty, then look at the Windows Event Viewer, MYSQL writes to that before it opens its own text error log, and if the error happens before that the only info will be on the Event Log

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you say does not add up. You say you are getting this error

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Which means that MYSQL is up and accepting connections.

Then you say that you get errors trying to start MYSQL???

The only possible reason for this is that you have 2 MYSQL Server instances running on this PC.

I suggest you uninstall the one that was there before you installed WAMPServer, after backing up any databases you may have created on it, so you can restore them to WAMPServers MYSQL

Also by default the MYSQL with WAMPServer comes with a single userid called `root` of course, and that account has NO PASSWORD.

Comment: This is all correct, and to add to my friend's answer it appears as if some of the troubleshooting steps you've taken have come from bad sources. For example, `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` refers to the hostname or IP address of the MySQL server, not the URL you use to load phpMyAdmin. 127.0.0.1 would be correct here, and the port number (which is 3306, the port MySQL is listening on, not your web server) would be set through `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']` but again, port 8888 is the webserver port, not the MySQL server port so you shouldn't modify the port at all.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch All very true, post that as an answer and it will get my Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

As @RiggsFolly has stated, it appears you have problems with your MySQL server. Something is answering phpMyAdmin, but but the WAMP MySQL server is not running and is in an error state. The first step is to solve what's going on there. Look in the WAMP and MySQL error logs to determine why the WAMP MySQL server didn't start (it's probably because of the other MySQL server already running on port 3306).

Furthermore, it appears as if some of the troubleshooting steps you've taken have come from bad sources. For example, $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] refers to the hostname or IP address of the MySQL server, not the URL you use to load phpMyAdmin. 127.0.0.1 would be correct here, and the port number (which is 3306, the port MySQL is listening on, not your web server) would be set through $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] but again, port 8888 is the webserver port, not the MySQL server port so you shouldn't modify the port at all. You'll have to have a correct settings in `config.inc.php` for phpMyAdmin to connect to your MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use root as username and leave password field as empty.
It worked for me.Hope it helps someone !!