# Wamp Displays Orange Icon- Apache Is Running and MySQL Won't Start

Tags: mysql, service, wamp

I am trying to run Wamp on my computer. Wamp was working up until I tried to use it today. I had changed the ini file for MySQL, but when it stopped working, I reverted the change. It still is not working. Apache is running because I can start and stop that service, and the icon changes color accordingly. Here is an image of what I mean:
[image: MySQL says it is running, but start does not work and restart and stop service causes an error]

Here is my mysql .ini file:

```
 # Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
 #
 # This is for a large system with memory of 1G-2G where the system runs mainly
# MySQL.
#
# MySQL programs look for option files in a set of
# locations which depend on the deployment platform.
# You can copy this option file to one of those
# locations. For information about these locations, see:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/option-files.html
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password = your_password
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld64]
#skip-grant-tables
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 1M

#Added to reduce memory used (minimum is 400)
table_definition_cache = 600

sort_buffer_size = 2M
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
#Path to mysql install directory
basedir="C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.9"
log-error="C:/wamp64/logs/mysql.log"
#Verbosity Value  1 Errors only, 2  Errors and warnings , 3 Errors, warnings, and notes
log_error_verbosity=2
#Path to data directory
datadir="C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.9/data"

#Path to the language
#See Documentation:
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html
lc-messages-dir="C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.9/share"
lc-messages=en_US

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
# New for MySQL 5.6 default_tmp_storage_engine if skip-innodb enable
# default_tmp_storage_engine=InnoDB

#To avoid warning messages
secure_file_priv="C:/wamp64/tmp"
skip-ssl

explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true

# Set the SQL mode to strict
#sql-mode=""
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
#
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
#binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)

# New for MySQL 5.6 if no slave
skip-slave-start

#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir   = /tmp/
#log-update   = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
# Chemins de mes bases de donn�es qui sont d�plac�es
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:/mysql/data/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:/mysql/data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:/mysql/data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size_size = 20M
read_buffer_size = 2M
write_buffer_size = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

Here is my MySQL Log file info:

```
2016-05-31T14:32:28.277983Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*320 pages, LSN=2472423
2016-05-31T14:32:28.480508Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2016-05-31T14:32:28.984623Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2472423
2016-06-14T19:25:07.247490Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 482  user: 'root'

2017-07-14T01:50:50.741198Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 30  user: 'root'

2017-07-14T01:50:50.761198Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 27  user: 'root'

2017-07-14T01:50:50.766200Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 26  user: 'root'

2017-07-14T01:50:50.772199Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 29  user: 'root'

2017-07-15T06:59:13.799344Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 11  user: 'root'

2017-07-15T06:59:13.846464Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 12  user: 'root'

2017-07-27T01:17:26.477513Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 688  user: 'root'

2017-07-27T01:17:26.517496Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 689  user: 'root'

2017-08-05T19:22:30.560951Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 305  user: 'root'

2017-08-05T19:22:30.631940Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 304  user: 'root'

2017-08-07T06:37:28.699452Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 12  user: 'root'

2017-08-07T06:37:28.701453Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 13  user: 'root'

2017-08-26T00:24:35.765816Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 24  user: 'root'

2017-08-26T00:24:35.802819Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 23  user: 'root'
```

Here is the status of the services:

```
State of services:

 The service 'wampapache64' is started

 The service 'wampmysqld64' is NOT started
 EXIT error code:0
 Help message for error code 0 is:
The operation completed successfully.



 The service 'dnscache' is started

WampServer (Apache, PHP and MySQL) will not function properly if any service
'wampapache64'
'wampmysqld64'
'dnscache'
 is not started.
```

Thank you for the help!

### Update

In services, mysqld.exe is always running and wampmysql64 is always starting.. When I kill mysqld.exe, I have the option of starting the MySQL service. When I start the service, the same error occurs.

Here is a photo of the error that occurs when I hit stop or restart the service:

[image]

Comment: It is very ODD that both the `Start/Resume Service` and `Stop Service` are both available. One should be greyed out, depending on the service being started or stopped??? You didn't install another MySQL Server on this PC by any chance did you?? Maybe as part of `MySQL Workbench` ??

Comment: The service is stuck in an infinite state of starting in services.

Comment: I did not install mysql, but I did install a .jar file to allow java to connect to mysql.

Comment: If you have a service called `MYSQL` as well as a service called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64` Then there is another instance of MYSQL installed on this PC. Up to you want you do with it! I would backup all the databases used by the MYSQL instance and then uninstall it. Then restore all the databases to the WAMPServer instance of MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix

I downloaded the current version of wamp in a new folder. I then copied the MySQL folder from the bin. I added my databases and modified the my.ini and wampserver.conf files to make them point to the right directory. This fixed my issue. I hope this helps others!

Comment: Not sure this is a good solution, or exactly what your solution was!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this post: [Wampserver icon not going green fully, mysql services not starting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761931/wampserver-icon-not-going-green-fully-mysql-services-not-starting-up#answer-19175432)

to quote the author:

> 1. Open wampserver's mysql log file. This will contain information on why the service threw and error and exited prematurely.
> 2. In my case, the mysql service failed to start because it could not read a certain tablespace. The specific tablespace was indicated in the log.
> 3. Failure to read such a file could be because of file permissions or the file being broken. In such a case, mysql stops executing in order to avoid damaging a tablespace file that may be linked to a database you need. Usually, if you have a backup of the database, then it is safe to simply delete this problematic file and restore the database once your mysql service is started again.
> 4. If you do not have a database backup then you could force the mysql instance to run a recovery by enabling the option in your my.cnf / my.ini file.
>
> innodb_force_recovery = 1
>
> This forces the instance to run the crash recovery.
>
> **NOTE:** installing a new instance of mysql does not necessarily mean that your databases shall be retained. I suggest you run a nightly backup of your databases if you are working on huge projects.

Comment: The log file info has been added. Please check and let me know if you can see anything useful in it. I checked that first and could not understand what the error was.

Comment: You have not shown us anthing containing an error??

Comment: Wampmysql64 is stuck starting while mysqld.exe is always running.