# MySQL service not working after upgrading from version 5.7.31 to version 8.0.27

Tags: mysql, database, wamp

After updating to the latest MySQL version on WampServer, I am unable to execute MySQL service. There was supposed to be a green colour check icon next to "Service administration 'wampmysql64'," but it disappeared, and I can't select any of the options like "Start/Resume Service," "Stop Service," or "Restart Service."
Is anyone facing the same issue?
[image]

Comment: Did you check the log file, see if this question could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761931/wampserver-icon-not-going-green-fully-mysql-services-not-starting-up

Comment: Go to the [WAMPServer Backup Repo](https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en) Go to the bottom on the page and download from the Tools section the utility called `Checks VC++ packages installed`, run it and it will tell you which MSVC Runtime libraries you are missing!! Once you know that go back and download the MSVC Runtimes from the bottom of the same page (If you are using a 64 bit OS and Wampserver remember to install both 32bit and 64bit versions.

Comment: You may have to uninstall the MySQL version 8.0.27 and reinstall it. The MSVC Runtimes are required for the install as well as normal running of the software